# how to do initialize the weight in h2o.deeplearning?

Tags: r, neural-network, deep-learning, h2o

I used `h2o.deeplearning` function to performe DNN in R.

I want to initialze the weights for the iteration and performance improvement of the Deep neural network.

I know that weighing initialization should be a small value between -1 and +1 rather than a large value.

Then, what is the parameter code in `h2o.deeplearning` that initialze the weight???? And how to use it to initialze between -1 and +1??

please help me..!

Answer (score 1):

If we check the documentation of `?h2o.deeplearning`

> initial_weights  A list of H2OFrame ids to initialize the weight
>   matrices of this model with.

Here is an example to set the weights

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
iris.hex <- as.h2o(iris)
iris.dl <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:4, y = 5, training_frame = iris.hex,
    hidden=c(10,10),export_weights_and_biases = TRUE
)
w1 <- h2o.weights(iris.dl,1)
w2 <- h2o.weights(iris.dl,2)
w3 <- h2o.weights(iris.dl,3)
b1 <- h2o.biases(iris.dl,1)
b2 <- h2o.biases(iris.dl,2)
b3 <- h2o.biases(iris.dl,3)

dl <- h2o.deeplearning(1:4,5,iris.hex,hidden=c(10,10),initial_weights=c(w1,w2,w3),
    initial_biases=c(b1,b2,b3))

p1 <- h2o.predict(dl, iris.hex)
p1
#  predict    setosa   versicolor    virginica
#1  setosa 0.9967546 0.0032424531 2.946375e-06
#2  setosa 0.9943469 0.0056346023 1.845851e-05
#3  setosa 0.9990881 0.0009072309 4.663780e-06
#4  setosa 0.9990550 0.0009393998 5.593951e-06
#5  setosa 0.9985592 0.0014391955 1.568052e-06
#6  setosa 0.9966511 0.0033477623 1.121636e-06

#[150 rows x 4 columns]
```

Regarding the normalization, it will be done by `h2o`.  Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798134/h2o-deep-learning-weights-and-normalization)